# Cytoscape uses memory of max 247.5 Mb

Tags: memory, ram, cytoscape

having some RAM issue in Cytoscape (9.1 and previous versions) on Windows 10.
The bottom right corner tells me 100% used of 247.5Mb.
I have 32gb available and the Cytocape.vmoptions file contains
-Xms2048M
-Xmx31019M
including [CR] and [LF]

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKHlD.png)

Can I somehow increase those 250mb?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it. In case anyone is having the same issue:
Previously, I did rename the Cytoscape.exe (added the version number in order to distinguish them). This seems to reset Cytoscape to use minimum memory only.
Renaming it back to default (Cytoscape.exe) sets the memory to hardware maximum.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi,

Glad you fixed it!  For a more completely answer, there is a file in the installation directory for Cytoscape called "Cytoscape.vmoptions".  That file contains all of your memory options.  Not quite sure why renaming the exe file would make Cytoscape not find that file, but it's certainly possible.